# Is there a list of existing, and planned, ISE versions of connectors?

Tags: azure-logic-apps

Is there a list of existing, and planned, ISE versions of connectors?

The existing list of Logic App [connectors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/connectors/) is fine, but it doesn't detail the ones which are also available as ISE variants.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From MSDN ...

*Eventually Product Group is planning to support all these in the near future but this timeline is subject to change.*

*As far as new features go, we are not able to disclose much at this time.*